# Extracting Fileds from Payload Dateweave

Tags: dataweave, mule4

Am trying to Extract only two fields from input data and set as variable inn mule 4

Input:

```
{
   "Id": "a9PV00000",
   "OwnerId": "00570000001c9fmAAA",
   "IsDeleted": "false",
   "Name": "Account",
   "CreatedDate": "2020-08-05T16:08:49.000Z",
   "CreatedById": "00570000001c9fmAAA",
   "LastModifiedDate": "2020-08-26T13:24:33.000Z",
   "LastModifiedById": "00570000001c9fmAAA",
   "SystemModstamp": "2020-09-04T13:09:57.000Z",
   "LastActivityDate": [],
   "LastViewedDate": "2020-09-09T08:10:29.000Z",
   "LastReferencedDate": "2020-09-09T08:10:29.000Z",
   "Object_API_Name__c": "Account",
   "Active__c": "true",
   "Upload_files_attachments__c": "true",
   "Delete_files_attachments__c": "false",
   "Folder_Name_": "Google Drive Notes and Attachments",
   "Parent_Folder_": "1oV_wWX-19ut"
}
```

Am using below expression in transform message

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload map (Sample, indexOfSamples) ->{
    "name": Sample.Name,
    "parentId": Sample.Parent_Folder
    
}
```

But its now working. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Do you have repeating objects like these or is it just one object from where you need to pick these values ? As well the map iterates over an array to output another/new array. What you have is an object instead.

Answer (score 0):

How about directly accessing the required fields?

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
     "name": payload.Name,
    "parentId": payload.Parent_Folder_
    
}
```